# Implement global application settings in C++

Tags: c++, configuration, singleton, global-variables, application-settings

I have a relatively big academic simulation software (50 classes). The user selects a configuration file which contains over 20 items. These constant variables are used all over the simulation platform (almost in every class). The simulation runs hundreds of thousands of agent objects a few times per second so the performance is important.

Currently I use a singleton Settings class. I use the instance to get the values which have been read from file into the class at program start (I did not want to add a reference to settings class in every other classe).

1- I recently ran a profiler and found that the excessive calls to getInstance().getSomeSetting() are hugging the performance.

2- Every time I talked about the singleton use, I received a lot of condemnations.

What is the best practice of accessing settings in such a scenario? Should I use global variables for these 20+ configuration items?

Comment: I do not believe that calling gettters can extremely decrease the performance (even in Debug mode, but I'm sure, you're at Release). Only if you're reading config file every time (I think you're not). "Should I use global variables for these 20+ configuration items?". Your singletone **is** a set of global variables. Show the code of the Settings class.

Comment: I know singleton is considered equal to a global variable (but not exactly, because I am calling two functions every time). Singleton class is a standard one and I read the file just once. It does not decrease the performance extremely. It hits the performance more than I expected (say around 3-4%).

Comment: How often do you call `getInstance().getSomeSetting()`? Do you cache the settings in local variables or class members after reading them?

Comment: If `getInstance` is defined in header and get-functions are very simple and you can define them in header too, then compiler should optimize that calls to straight accessing to appropriate members of `Settings` class. Or you can help compiler by mark getters with `inline` directive. I can believe to 3-4% only if the least of code (useful computation as a matter of fact) is very very small

Comment: @TAS: that's the point. I use it more than a few times for each run which results into a few hundred thousand times a second. And yes, I read the settings into the class variables (which are then accessible through setter/getters)

Comment: I modified the Settings class and converted into a simple Static class. That saves the burden of getInstance. I guess it has been effective.

Comment: @borisbn I guess most of the burden was from the getInstance(). It compares to see whether the class is created or not (conditional statement, comparison, assignments) and of course one more stack operation (i.e. function call).

Comment: "converted into a simple Static class" hmmm... what is `Static class` ? "It compares to see whether the class is created or not" - you can return a reference to an instance, created as `static` inside `getInstance()` like this: `Settings & getInstance() { static Settings s( params /*maybe*/ ); return s; }`

Comment: Static class refers to a class with all static functions. It somehow is equal to Static classes in Java and C#.

Comment: @wmac When are the settings read?

Comment: @TAS Obviously once, at the creation of the instance.

Comment: @wmac One option would be to use a factory class to create each instance. Then the factory can read the settings once when it is created and then pass the settings directly to the objects through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the configuration object in a shared_ptr and pass it anywhere you want, in this way you will have a single settings object

Comment: Pass a pointer to 50+ classes (+possible forward decelerations etc.)?